# Controlar dirección de una nave con bool c++

Tags: c++, animación, booleano

estoy haciendo un programa donde tengo una nave que sigue un camino definido en un arreglo, pero agregue dos variables tipo bool para controlar la dirección en la que se imprime la nave, lo cual no funciona, lo que requiero es saber como hago que esas variables funcionen para utilizarlas cuando yo quiera en ese u otro recorrido diferente.

Por ejemplo:

Tengo dos variables bool, izqder que controla izquierda y derecha, y arrab que controla arriba y abajo.

Entonces lo que quiero es que mi programa sepa que cuando "x" este aumentando, izqder sea true para que vaya a la derecha y cuando disminuya a la izquierda y el de arrab para que cuando "y" este aumentando sea true y vaya hacia abajo y cuando disminuya que vaya hacia arriba.

Por aqui abajo dejare un avance de mi código para que lo analicen y vean si con mi lógica pueden apoyarme.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;
void OcultarCursor(){
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    cci.dwSize = 100;
    cci.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}

int main()
{
    system("mode con: cols=100 lines=50");
    OcultarCursor();
    int x,y,filaanterior;
    char forma;
    bool vertical=true;
    bool derecha=true;
    bool abajo=true;
    int fila;
    int ArregloMapa1[][2]={ { 5, 5 }, { 5, 6 }, { 5, 7 }, { 5, 8 }, { 5, 9 }, { 5, 10 }, { 5, 11 }, { 5, 12 }, { 5, 13 }, { 5, 14 }, { 5, 15 }, { 6, 15 }, { 7, 15 }, { 8, 15 }, { 9, 15 }, { 10, 15 }, { 11, 15 }, { 12, 15 }, { 13, 15 }, { 14, 15 }, { 15, 15 }, { 16, 15 }, { 17, 15 }, { 18, 15 }, { 19, 15 }, { 20, 15 }, { 21, 15 },{ 22, 15 },{ 23, 15 },{ 24, 15 },{ 25, 15 },{ 26, 15 },{ 27, 15 },{ 28, 15 },{ 29, 15 },{ 30, 15 },{ 31, 15 },{ 32, 15 },{ 33, 15 },{ 34, 15 },{ 35, 15 },{ 36, 15 },{ 37, 15 },{ 38, 15 },{ 39, 15 },{ 40, 15 },{ 41, 15 },{ 42, 15 },{ 43, 15 },{ 44, 15 },{ 45, 15 },{ 46, 15 },{ 47, 15 },{ 48, 15 },{ 49, 15 },{ 50, 15 },{ 50, 16 },{ 50, 17 },{ 50, 18 },{ 50, 19 },{ 50, 20 },{ 50, 21 },{ 50, 22 },{ 50, 23 },{ 50, 24 },{ 50, 25 },{ 49, 25 },{ 48, 25 },{ 47, 25 },{ 46, 25 },{ 45, 25 },{ 44, 25 },{ 43, 25 },{ 42, 25 },{ 41, 25 },{ 40, 25 },{ 39, 25 },{ 38, 25 },{ 37, 25 },{ 36, 25 },{ 35, 25 },{ 34, 25 },{ 33, 25 },{ 32, 25 },{ 31, 25 },{ 30, 25 },{ 29, 25 },{ 28, 25 },{ 27, 25 },{ 26, 25 },{ 25, 25 },{ 24, 25 },{ 23, 25 },{ 22, 25 },{ 21, 25 },{ 20, 25 },{ 19, 25 },{ 18, 25 },{ 17, 25 },{ 16, 25 },{ 15, 25 }};

            x=ArregloMapa1[1][0];
            y=ArregloMapa1[1][1];
            int tamaarreglo=sizeof ArregloMapa1 / sizeof ArregloMapa1[0];
            //  tamaarreglo=11;
            //cout<<"x="<<x<<" y="<<y;
            cout << "Length of array = " << tamaarreglo << std::endl;


    for (fila =0; fila<tamaarreglo; fila++){
            x=ArregloMapa1[fila][0]; //Columna 1
            y=ArregloMapa1[fila][1]; //Columna 2
            filaanterior=fila-1;

            if(filaanterior<0){
                    //filaanterior=0;

            }else{if(ArregloMapa1[fila][0]!=ArregloMapa1[filaanterior][0]){
                    vertical=false;
            }else{vertical=true;}}



             if(vertical){forma=printf("%c",186);}
             else{forma=printf("%c",205);}

            gotoxy(x,y); //cout<<forma;
    }

    Sleep(50);

    if(abajo==true){
        for (fila =0; fila<tamaarreglo; fila++){
            gotoxy(x-2,y-2); cout<<"     ";
            gotoxy(x-2,y-1); cout<<"     ";
            gotoxy(x-2,y);   cout<<"     ";
            x=ArregloMapa1[fila][0];
            y=ArregloMapa1[fila][1];
            gotoxy(x-2,y-2); cout<<"** **";
            gotoxy(x-2,y-1); cout<<" *** ";
            gotoxy(x-2,y);   cout<<"  *  ";
            Sleep(500);
        }
    }
    if(derecha==true){
    for (fila =0; fila<tamaarreglo; fila++){
            gotoxy(x,y-2); cout<<"   ";
            gotoxy(x,y-1); cout<<"   ";
            gotoxy(x,y);   cout<<"   ";
            gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<"   ";
            gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<"   ";
            x=ArregloMapa1[fila][0];
            y=ArregloMapa1[fila][1];
            gotoxy(x,y-2); cout<<"*  ";
            gotoxy(x,y-1); cout<<"** ";
            gotoxy(x,y);   cout<<" **";
            gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<"** ";
            gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<"*  ";
            Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema.

Tienes un terrible fallo de diseño, que es precisamente la premisa de toda tu pregunta:

> Tengo dos variables `bool`, `izqder` que controla izquierda y derecha, y `arrab` que controla arriba y abajo.

> Quiero es que mi programa sepa que cuando "x" este aumentando, `izqder` sea `true` [...] `arrab` para que cuando "y" este aumentando sea `true`

El problema es que estás asumiendo que izquierda es lo mismo que no-derecha y arriba es lo mismo que no-abajo, y eso no es del todo cierto. Con tu diseño tu nave nunca estará quieta y además nunca navegará recto. Veamos la tabla de la verdad de tus variables `izqder` y `arrab` y el desplazamiento asociado:

```
| izqder | arrab | movimiento |
+--------+-------+------------+
|  false | false |      ↙     |
|  false | true  |      ↖     |
|  true  | false |      ↘     |
|  true  | true  |      ↗     |
```

Esto sucede porque el hecho de no estar desplazándose a la izquierda no implica estar desplazándose a la derecha, también puedes ser que no se esté aplicando movimiento horizontal, lo mismo para el desplazamiento vertical.

Así pues, no puedes controlar la dirección de una nave con `bool`.

#### Propuesta.

Usa una variable de tipo [vector geométrico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector):

```
struct vector_geometrico { int x, y; };
```

O aprovecha la [`COORD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/coord-str) que ya usas en otras partes de tu programa. Si la nave no se está desplazando, tanto `x` como `y` serán `0`, y si se mueve a la izquierda `x` tendrá valor negativo, siendo positivo para desplazarse a la derecha. Lo mismo para desplazarse arriba y abajo y la variable `y`.